# Cannot delete elements from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm having in my textfield three email id's. These three emails are also stored in an array called `feedbackEmailsArray`. These email id's are also separated from each other by a comma.

But in case I don't want an email, then when I click on the backspace button and completely delete an email id, then I also want it to be deleted from my `feedbackEmailsArray`.

How can I achieve this..?

**EDIT 1**: This is how I'm deleting the email id:

```
    if let char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
        if (isBackSpace == -92) {

           //Backspace was pressed
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some code how are you deleting the email id exactly?

Comment: @GautamShrivastav I have added the code that shows how I'm deleting the email

Comment: And I have added that code within `textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range`

Comment: But how can we know if the email id was deleted from the textfield completely..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

First you split the string in your textfield into parts based on ' , '. Then we clear the `feedbackEmailsArray` and then add the emails back into the `feedbackEmailsArray`

`validateEmail` will check if the current string is a valid email or not, if its valid email, it will be added to the array. `validateEmail` could be made a global function or a static function if you want to use it anywhere in the program.

```
func validateEmail(email:String) -> Bool {

    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)
    return emailPredicate.evaluate(with: email)

}

var emailIds = yourtextfield.text
var emailIdsArr = emailIds.split(separator: ",")
feedbackEmailsArray.removeAll()
for i in(0..<emailIdsArr.count) where emailIdsArr.indices.contains(i)
{

    if validateEmail(email:emailIdsArr[i]) == true
    { feedbackEmailsArray.append(emailIdsArr[i]) }

}
```

**Explanation** : @testname The `validateEmail` function checks if the stuff you typed are in a valid format or not, that is, 'abc@abc.com'. Now, everytime you backspace in that email field, `emailIds` variable will get that entire string (abc@abc.com,bcd@bcd.com,asd@a). In this string, asd@a is not a valid email. Now `emailIDs.split` will split the string in `emailIds` variable based on the number on `,` character. These are stored in the `emailIdsArr` as `emailIdArr[0],emailIdArr[1],emailIdArr[2]...`

The for loop gets the total number of indexs in the `emailIdArr` by using emailIdArr.count. The `where emailIdsArr.indices.contains(i)` is a simple checking to check if the index is valid. Just to make it crash proof(was added by @iOSDev into my answer).

Now `validateEmail` is called and we give the argument as a string at index of `emailIdsArr[i]` (eg. i = 5 then index = 5 , so validateEmail(email:5@5.com) will return true as it's in an emailId format)

`validateEmail` is a boolean function that returns true if the string is in emailID format and return false if it isn't.

So if `validateEmail` returns true, that email gets appended to `feedbackEmailsArray`.

Since we are using append and the number of emailIds can be changed anytime, we have to clear the entire array every time this entire function gets called, hence the `feedbackEmailsArray.removeAll()` placed outside and above the for-loop.

Comment: The number of emails can be any number. Not just 3

Comment: @testname Edited the answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: will try @Zyfe3r

Comment: @Zyfe3rIn the answer above, are you checking if the email that is being deleted is a valid email or not & if it's not, deleting it from the array..?

Comment: would you mind suggesting as to how the solution works..?

Comment: @testname check the answer again, i have added an explanation to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation @Zyfe3r. Cannot upvote now since my reputation is less than 15. Once it is more than 15, will surely upvote...:)